# Average number of bits required to store one letter of British English using perfect compression in python

Tags: python, algorithm, compression

I have an assignment which is written under:

*What is the average number of bits required to store one letter of British English if perfect
compression is used?*

Since the entropy of an experiment can be interpreted as the minimum number of bits required to store its result. I tried making a program calculating the entropy of all letters and then add them all together to find the Entropy of all letters.

this gives me 4.17 bits but according to [this link](http://i308.wikispaces.com/Information+Content,+Compression+and+Encryption)

With a perfect compression algorithm we should only need 2 bits per character!

So how do I implement this perfect compression algorithm on this?

```
import math
letters=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
sum =0

def find_perc(s):

perc=[0.082,0.015,0.028,0.043,0.127,0.022,0.02,0.061,0.07,0.002,0.008,0.04,0.024,0.067,0.075,0.019,0.001,0.060,0.063,0.091,0.028,0.01,0.023,0.001,0.02,0.001]

letter=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
pos = 0
temp = s.upper()
if temp in letter:
    for x in xrange(1,len(letter)):
        if temp==letter[x]:
            pos = x
return perc[pos]

def calc_ent(s):
P=find_perc(s)
sum=0
    #Calculates the Entropy of the current letter
temp = P *(math.log(1/P)/math.log(2)) 

    #Does the same thing just for binary entropy (i think)
#temp = (-P*(math.log(P)/math.log(2)))-((1-P)*(math.log(1-P)/math.log(2)))
sum=temp
return sum


for x in xrange(0,25):
    sum=sum+calc_ent(letters[x])

print "The min bit is : %f"%sum
```

Comment: Note that the author is on SO: @Matt Mahoney but not really active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you link to again links to this page:

[Refining the Estimated Entropy of English by Shannon Game Simulation](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/dissertation/entropy1.html)

If you read carefully, the entropy computed there is not naively computed using the probability of occurrences for each letters - instead, it is computed by

> The subject was shown the previous 100 characters of text and asked to guess the next character until successful

So I think you are not wrong, only the method you use differ - using only naive occurrence probability data, you cannot compress the information that well, but if you take the context into consideration, then there are so much more the redundant information. E.g., `e` has a probability of 0.127, but for `th_`, `e` probably has something more like 0.3.

Comment: Also as any cryptographer will tell you (well linguist really), there are many more rules in English for that kind of thing. For example q is pretty much always followed by a u, etc.

Comment: Okay! I think what was throwing me off was "perfect compression". So finding the entropy is the same as the size of perfect compression?

Comment: Yeah but this assingment was for one letter only not for common duplets and triplets

Comment: Should be since the entropy is the information, and you cannot use any bit less to represent the information. Since the assignment is for one letter, I guess your answer should be fine - it is just as if you are working with a shuffled English text, with the same letter distribution but the other information destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as perfect compression, since it is provably impossible to compute the number of bits if "perfect compression" is applied.  See [Kolmogorov Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).

You will not be able to implement a compressor in a few lines of code that approaches what appears to be the limits of the compressibility of English text by computer programs, around one bit per character.  Humans may be able to do a [little better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29).

Comment: @Becktor http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Adler Now I believe that whatever Mark told us on this is right:) +1

Comment: If instead we describe what the OP intended to do as "per-charcter perfect compression", will that be okay? Or maybe it already has some different canonical name?